# How can I make cardamom coffee with my Aeropress?

Tags: aeropress, flavored-coffee

I once had a cardamom coffee at a mosque,  and I've been trying to recreate it.

I've tried with my cafitierre with no success. Is it possible to do so with my Aeropress?

Comment: You mean [green cardamom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elettaria_cardamomum), right? Have you tried grinding the pods/seeds, or what have you tried? Mashing the seeds/pods should work, or perhaps steeping the seeds in water before brewing the coffee. Actually, there's a [previous question about the same thing](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/2131/262) -- and by happenstance an answer by me ;-). I'll add some more detail there. If you've tried these and it doesn't work for you, perhaps we can re-open the topic...